# UserDefaults - not saving consistently when using Xcode Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, userdefaults

I am learning iOS development and I have stumbled across an issue where UserDefaults doesn't seem to be consistently saving correctly.

When I open the app, it checks to see if a UserDefaults property exists, if so, it does something. Now, if I save the UserDefaults property and 'synchronize', then press stop on the simulator and then press 'play' again to re-open it, sometimes the UserDefaults value is nil.

I have yet to test this on a physical device, but has anyone had the same issue - if so, is it expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe UserDefaults work fine but when you save some data to UserDefaults and rebuild or run use `Command + R` if already running simulator
then sometimes nothing changed (saved data disappear)

so everytime when this situation(have to save some data to `UserDefaults` , `CoreData` or `Realm`) I stop and exit simulator first and rebuild or run Xcode

it works fine to me

Comment: I'll give that a go, so what you are saying it to exit the simulator before pressing the 'Play Button'?